# How do I choose and play a local audio file in HTML5/Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to write a simple HTML5 media player that can play a local audio file. The Phonegap Media API seems like the perfect tool for my services, but from what I can tell it assumes I know the exact file I want to play.

I'd like to be able to let the user choose the file he wants to play from local storage and then play that file. Is this possible?

Comment: when you are asking some question please show your research efforts done by you to figure out this problem don't just directly ask for codes. Like see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899110/observing-changes-in-android-content-observer-for-audio-media-external-content-u

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial that should definitely help you with this!

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/build-an-audioplayer-with-phonegap-application-setup/